# JavaFX VBox multiple elements on one row

Tags: java, layout, javafx

How could I have more than one elements in one row using JavaFX and VBox. Lets say that I need a TextField and a Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in a `HBox`, and put the `HBox` in the `VBox`.

```
VBox vbox = ... ;
TextField textField = ... ;
Button button = ... ;

HBox hbox = new HBox(textField, button);
vbox.getChildren().add(hbox);
```